# При попытке отправить команду в другой канал, она отправляется в текущий

Tags: discord, discord.py

Изначально я хотел, чтобы команда срабатывала там, куда я укажу.

Пример: **[Префикс][Команда][#Канал]**

Допустим, у меня есть команда, которая отправляет текст и локальные картинки, но какой бы канал я не указал, всё отправляется в тот, где я писал команду.

```
@commands.has_permissions(administrator = True)
@bot.command()
async def text_and_image(ctx, channel: discord.TextChannel):
    await ctx.message.delete()
    await ctx.send('''Текст''', 
    file=discord.File(r'D:\Папка\Картинка.png'))
```

Я подумал, что проблема в картинке, и попытался отправить простой текст, но и он не отправлялся в нужный канал. Тоже самое происходит с embed.

Comment: Так может стоит явно указать в какой канал вы шлете?)) сейчас вы шлете в тот же канал в котором произошло событие ```await ctx.send('''Текст''',file=discord.File(r'D:\Папка\Картинка.png'))``` вы тут видите упоминание *channel* ? я - не вижу

Comment: Мне не нужно вписывать id конкретного канала.
Допустим, мне нужно отправить команду в один канал, и всё будет работать, но если это надо повторить для другого канала, то что делать? Менять один id на другой?

Не работает только команда, которая содержит в себе уже готовый текст или файл.

Comment: *всё отправляется в тот, где я писал команду.* ваши слова? Ваше сообщение отправляется в тот канал в котором была получена комманда, т.к. вы не изменили канал, ctx - указатель контекста с которого пришло сообщение, и ответ вы отправляете в тот же чат

Comment: И как быть?
_Просто я вообще не смыслю в программировании._

Comment: Не смыслите - или учитесь или не беритесь за это дело. У вас два пути: 1) купить готовое решение\нанять человека. 2) Научиться программировать. 
Данный сайт создан для тех кто выбирает второй путь. Если ваш выбор таков же - стоит почитать хоть что то по теме. вы никак не передаете чат в который хотите отправить сообщение, и никак его не указываете. Начните чтение с описания библиотеки которой вы пользуетесь

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы создали аргумент `channel: discord.TextChannel`, но в команде его не используете

```py
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator = True)
async def text_and_image(ctx, channel: discord.TextChannel):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)
    await channel.send('''Текст''', file=discord.File(r'D:\Папка\Картинка.png'))
```

Comment: Это сработало! Спасибо вам огромное.

Comment: Скажите, зачем эта строка?

await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)

Comment: она удаляет сообщение в канале, в котором вы написали команду.